# Javascript check for empty spaces when css float:left

Tags: javascript

Okay now.. I really didn't know how to give this one a title. Here is my problem. I am trying to make a page where the body has a class defining the width of another div a.k.a `baser`.

I have a jQuery script that detects the width of the window and gives `body` a class hereafter. for example when the width of the window is about 900px - `body` will be given a class `.col_6`.

Each card is 150px in width, but when they have the additional class `large` they will be 300px in width. The problem now is that depending on the order of the `cards` in HTML, there will be some empty spaces if a `card.large` should be placed in a space only 150px wide. Then the card will automatically jump to next row and leave an open space of 150px in the previous row.

What I would like to know is - what can I add to my script to perhaps selecting a 150px wide card placed later in the order and move it in the empty spot or filling out the empty spot with a javascript made div ( for other purposes )..

I hope you are able to figure out my problem by reading this.. I have made a jsfiddle that shows my code and the problem. You can try resizing the window when reading the fiddle. It will show you how an empty space will be seen sometimes.

http://jsfiddle.net/EK8q2/4/

here is my javascript/jQuery if it can help you any way..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    winResize(window.innerWidth);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    winResize(window.innerWidth);
    // Room for more functions
});

function winResize(w) {
    resizeBaser(w);
    // Room for more functions
}

function resizeBaser(w) {
    var index = Math.min(10, Math.floor(w / 150));
    if (index > 0) {
        $('body').alterClass('col_*', 'col_' + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be opposed to using a library like masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Its really nice.. I might consider using it if nothing else comes up.. I really hate third party jquery plugins cause they mess with my css and they make the site so much more heavier to load..

Comment: I used to feel that way too. Perhaps you can just extract the logic that you need.

Comment: :) yeah.. but one thing that it doesn't support (and maybe what I have done wrong) is that every card is placed with `position:absolute` where mine is relatively placed..

Comment: Here is an article that might help: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: Is your question: how to reorder these cards to fill those empty places?

Comment: @stano yeah.. sort of..

Comment: Well, only for clarification: for example if you resize this window http://jsfiddle.net/EK8q2/5/show so that you will see the cards aligned like: `row1: 1234, row2: 567 and row3: 89`. Now how should the rows look like after reordering those cards? Something like: `row1: 1234, row2: 568, row3:79 (or maybe 97)`? or `row1:1234, row2:5679, row3:8`? Or is the order irrelevant?

Comment: For example. When using your fiddle and the body has class `col_4`then it would be nice that it would reorder number 9 so that it takes up empty space in second row. `row1: 1234, row2: 5679, row3: 8`..

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm as I see it is this:

1. Attach to `load/scroll/resize` events:

   $(window).on('load scroll resize', function () {

   });
2. There, group the `$('.card')` elements into an array of rows.

Something like:

```
var rowsObj = {}, rows = [];
$('.card').each(function(){
  var el = $(this), 
    pos = el.position(), 
    currentRow = rowsObj[pos.top] || (rowsObj[pos.top] = []);
  currentRow.push(el);
});
$.each(rowsObj, function(k, v) {
  if (/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(k)) {
    rows.push(v);
  }
});
// rows now contains array of arrays of $-ed elements
```

3. Then I'd enumerate the rows from end to start and tried to id all orphan cards (condition: single most narrow card) - having these, I'd search from top to bottom and tried to locate the possible new row (i.e. the last element of that potential row) and `orphan.insertAfter(thatElement)`. Upon insertion, I'd exclude both rows (one containing the orphan, the other - incomplete row) from the array. Do until no pairs (orphan-incomplete) can be formed.

4.Then I'd think on how to extend this logic to widths larger than single card.

Comment: Can't seem to find head and tail on this.. could you try using it in my fiddle so I can see it?

Comment: Here, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/andrevinsky/XgwCz/2/
Open console to see the output for the resulting page

Comment: I see it now.. but how do I make it actually perform the task and reorder?

Comment: Philip, the way I see it you should study your usage case. Is there a lot of times when your basic adjustment scheme doesn't work well? Is there a single one-cell card orphaned ever? From what I saw, nope.
Once you gather this data, you'll be able to see the pattern and will get idea how to proceed.